# Using the sftp protocol with libcurl -- How do I list the contents of a directory?

Tags: c++, curl, sftp, libcurl

I have a little doubt. I need to get a list of the files inside a specific directory on a SFTP server. I will use CUROPT_DIRLISTONLY in order to get just the names, but I'm not sure how to get them. This is the peace of code I have by now:

```
   string baseUrl(serverAddr + "/" + __destDir);
   curl_easy_setopt(anEasyHandle, CURLOPT_URL, (baseUrl).c_str());
   curl_easy_setopt(anEasyHandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,      1L);
   curl_easy_setopt(anEasyHandle, CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY, 1);
   curl_easy_setopt(anEasyHandle, CURLOPT_QUOTE, commandList);

   curl_easy_perform(anEasyHandle);

   curl_easy_reset(anEasyHandle);
```

If I'm right, curl_easy_perform just returns an ERROR_CODE (success or error ir it applies), correct? So where can I get the files list?

If I run it on a terminal: curl -u user:pass sftp://server/path/ -l I get the list I want....

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a "callback function" with the following signature:

```
size_t function( void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream);
```

You then call [curl_easy_setopt](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) to set the callback function as your CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION. Your function will be called for each chunk of data recieved from the remote server, which should be some form of directory listing.

**Disclaimer:** I have only read the [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) on this, not tried it.

Comment: A few moments after posting I found that same peace of information on the documentation. I'm trying and it seams to be working. Later I'll come back with better results. Thansk a lot.